# Debian services examples?

Tags: networking, services

I'm an IT teacher and one of my courses is dedicated to network services deployment on Debian.
I've taught my students about NFS, DHCP, Samba, FTP and HTTP servers.

I would like to evaluate them by asking them to deploy a new service that is not too complicated protocol-wise and configuration-heavy, but I don't have a lot of ideas.
I've tought about :

- DNS but it's too hard for their level
- NTP but there's not much to configure
- IRC but I can't find anything to setup

Therefore I'm a bit out of options.

So what network services comes to your mind that are quite interesting to discover ?

Comment: How about file sharing / host access? Setting up an ssh, SMB, or ftp service. Sharing files on a network and defining access rights seems both basic enough as well as close to a problem that makes sense to beginners.

Comment: IMO DNS is the most useful of the lot, with some guidance.

Answer (score 1):

SSHD is a very important one if not fundamental in today's behind the scenes operations. It also has very easy and next to out of the box configuration, which then can also get quite complex for more advanced applications. As an extension I'd introduce the concept of SSH tunnelling and setting up some simple proxy. This topic can be as wide as needed.

Comment: I'd also add socket-based activation for SSH using systemd.